# constructors refuse to be used

Tags: java, constructor, jgrasp

Currently using **jgrasp** to write a small program, using two different files in the same directory. In one file, I have a public class with several public constructors called Employee. In another file, I have a class that's meant to implement the Employee class. I cannot build this program -- the compiler tells me essentially that such provided constructors don't exist (see code below). Thus every build I make fails.

Constructors inside my Employee class have public access and as far as I can tell are named properly. I'm a C# kind of guy, so I don't know if I just don't see the issue because of my disposition or what. I'm leaning Java for a class currently at school.

Here is my Employee class:

```
public class Employee
{
   // description: class representation of an employee. 

   // variable declarations
   String name = "", department = "", position = "";
   int idNumber = 0;

   // constructors
   public Employee(String n, String d, String p, int id)
   {
      // full constructor
      this.name = n; 
      this.department = d; 
      this.position = p; 

      if (id > -1) this.idNumber = id; 
      else this.idNumber = 0; 
   }
   public Employee(String n, int id)
   {
      // partial constructor (name and id)
      this.name = n; 

      if (id > -1) this.idNumber = id; 
      else idNumber = 0; 

      this.department = ""; 
      this.position = ""; 
   }
   public Employee()
   {
      // default constructor
      this.name = ""; 
      this.department = ""; 
      this.position = ""; 
      this.idNumber = 1;
   }

   // accessors
   public String getName() { return name; }
   public String getDepartment() { return department; }
   public String getPosition() { return position; }
   public int getID() { return idNumber; }

   // mutators
   public void setName(String newName) { name = newName; }
   public void setDepartment(String newDepartment) { department = newDepartment; }
   public void setPosition(String newPosition) { position = newPosition; }
   public void setID(int newID) { idNumber = newID; }
}
```

Here is my implementation class:

```
public class ChallengeImplementor
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // create instance-variables for constructors
      String e1_name = "Susan Meyers", e2_name = "Mark Jones"; 
      string e1_department = "Accounting"; 
      string e1_position = "Vice President"; 
      int e1_ID = 47899, ew_ID = 39119; 

      // create several employee objects to prove they work. 
      Employee e1 = new Employee("Susan Meyers", "Accounting", "Vice President", 47899),  // created one with full constructor
               e2 = new Employee("Mark Jones", 39119),                                    // ... partial constructor
               e3 = new Employee();                                                       // ... default constructor

      // set values for e2 that weren't covered in partial constructor
      e2.setDepartment("IT"); 
      e2.setPosition("Programmer"); 

      // set values for e3
      e3.setName("Joy Rogers"); 
      e3.setDepartment("Manufacturing"); 
      e3.setPosition("Engineer"); 
      e3.setID(81774); 

      // display all three employees
      System.out.println("Name\t\tID\t\tDepartment\t\tPosition"); 
      System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
      System.out.println(e1.getName() + "\t" + e1.getID() + "\t\t" + e1.getDepartment() + "\t\t" + e1.getPosition()); 
      System.out.println(e2.getName() + "\t" + e2.getID() + "\t\t" + e3.getDepartment() + "\t\t" + e2.getPosition()); 
      System.out.println(e3.getName() + "\t" + e3.getID() + "\t\t" + e3.getDepartment() + "\t\t" + e3.getPosition()); 
   }
}
```

Comment: add the exact compiler error

Comment: Just a side note, but you may want to look into constructor overloading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your import statement are missing. Add it to the top of your class just below the package name.

```
import {full package name}.Employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
`e1_department` and `e1_position` are supposed to be **String** objects, but in **java**   there is no **string** (note the name as lowercase)

fix the typo by doing:

```
String e1_department = "Accounting";
String e1_position = "Vice President";
```

after this, the code is running as expected:

output:

[image]

Comment: would this result in a warning that *provided constructors don't exist*

Answer (score 0):

I took the code and ran your main function and got this response:

```
    Name        ID      Department      Position
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Susan Meyers    47899       Accounting      Vice President
    Mark Jones  39119       Manufacturing       Programmer
    Joy Rogers  81774       Manufacturing       Engineer
```

It looks good here.
Can you check if u have imported the package correctly?

Secondly I see two errors on the second and third field on your main function:
The fields are declared strings with small s, should be String.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to compile your program and it didn't work initially. The reason was that you have used primitive string type for your ChallengeImplementor fields:

```
  string e1_department = "Accounting"; 
  string e1_position = "Vice President";
```

Once I changed this to String, it compiled and worked just fine:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRwx.png).
Right click ChallengeImplementor.class and start it as a Java Application

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm a complete idiot. Somehow the Employee.java file was moved out of the same directory. I think jGrasp accidentally saved it somewhere else, even though that's where both files originally started.

I fixed the String issue -- that was actually just a test I was trying to perform and that code was never needed.

Comment: Even if it is not in the same package, you can use it by write an import statement.